# Java 8 streams - filter by comparing two lists

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have 2 lists which are different from one another

```
public class App1{
    private String name;
    private String city;

    // getter setter

    // constructors
}

public class App2{
    private String differentName;
    private String differentCity;
    private String someProperty1;
    private String someProperty2;

    // getter setter

    // constructors
}

List<App1> app1List = new ArrayList<>();
app1List.add(new App1("test1","city1"));
app1List.add(new App1("test2","city2"));
app1List.add(new App1("test3","city3"));
app1List.add(new App1("test4","city4"));

List<App2> app2List = new ArrayList<>();
app2List.add(new App2("test2","city2"));
app2List.add(new App2("test3","city3"));
```

As you see the App1 & App2 class are 2 different pojos having different property names, however the content/value that's held by name,city & differentName,differentCity property respectively is same i.e. test1, test2, test3 & city1, city2 etc

Now I need to filter app1List comparing names & city in other list i.e. app2List that doesn't exists.

final output would be

```
app1List.add(new App1("test1","city1"));
app1List.add(new App1("test4","city4"));
```

Easiest way is to loop one of the other lists multiple time which i am trying to avoid. Is there any way in Java 8 streams without having to loop multiple times??

Comment: Convert one list to a hashset first.

Comment: What if you had an input `app2List.add(new App2("test1","city4""));`  as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of `noneMatch` operation, such as:

```
List<App1> result = app1List.stream()
        .filter(app1 -> app2List.stream()
                .noneMatch(app2 -> app2.getDifferentCity().equals(app1.getCity()) &&
                        app2.getDifferentName().equals(app1.getName())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This assumes the combination of both `name` and `city` is matched while `filter`ing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `override` `equals` method in `App2` class:

```
public class App2{
    private String differentName;
    private String differentCity;
    private String someProperty1;
    private String someProperty2;

    // getter setter

    // constructors

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
       App2 app2 = (App2) obj;
       return this.differentName.equals(app2.getDifferentName()) && this.differentCity.equals(app2.getDifferentCity());
    }
}
```

and then you can use Streams on your list1 like this:

```
app1List = app1List.stream()
                .filter(a-> !app2List.contains(new App2(a.getName(),a.getCity())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Output:

`[App1{name='test1', city='city1'}, App1{name='test4', city='city4'}]`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you want to match both the name and the city, You could create a function that maps the **objects** to a **key**, for example:

```
public static Integer key(String name, String differentCity) {
    return Objects.hash(name, differentCity);
}
```

Then use the key to create a set of keys to filter by it using [noneMatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#noneMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-), for example:

```
Set<Integer> sieve = app2List.stream()
        .map(app2 -> key(app2.differentName, app2.differentCity)).collect(Collectors.toSet());

List<App1> result = app1List.stream().filter(app1 -> sieve.stream()
        .noneMatch(i -> i.equals(key(app1.name, app1.city))))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(result);
```

**Output**

```
[App1{name='test1', city='city1'}, App1{name='test4', city='city4'}]
```

The complexity of this approach is `O(n + m)` where `n` and `m` are the lengths of the list.